# Available plugins are not getting listed in SonarQube 5.6.6 version

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube version 5.6.6 is not showing the available plugins. I have signed in as admin and still it is showing as 0 available. Screen shot attached

[image: Error shown]

Comment: From what I see in your screenshot you're using version 5.6.6 and not 6.3.1

Comment: In addition to what @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam said, you should be aware that the Update Center requires access to the Internet.